# How to run a profiler with automated regression test suit on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, profiling, regression-testing

I have started a new project and have a few regression tests written using Karate (more will be added with new features). I also have an automated build on Jenkins that runs this regression suite on an AWS instance. I would like to have a profiler run and provide a report while these tests are running so that I can identify hotspots and (potential) issues with each new submission of code and address it sooner rather than later. Is there something provided in AWS that can achieve this for me, or can it be done through Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

[JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has [ant](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.commandLine.antTasks) and [Gradle](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.commandLine.gradleTasks) plugins that can be used for automating profiling sessions and also for extracting reports from the saved snapshots.

You can use these plugins with Jenkins via its own ant or Gradle plugins.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. JProfiler is the tool I had in mind as I have the most experience with it. I’ll look into those plugins!

Comment: @MeanwhileInHell hi - I'm the dev of Karate, you may have noticed the JaCoCo integration in the demo, which may be a good reference. if you have your Karate tests in the *same* Maven module as your server-side code, this should be very easy: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#code-coverage-using-jacoco